# Backbone.js Combine two collection into one

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Is there any method in backbone or underscore for adding two collections into one. I want two or more collections to added to one collection .Basically have two collections

first collection

```
[
    {
        name: "Bob"
        date: "Thu Mar 29 2012"
    },
    {
        name: "James"
        date: "Fri Mar 30 2012"
    },

]
```

second collection

```
[
   {
        name: "Dylan"
        date: "Fri Mar 30 2012"
    },
    {
        name: "Stanley"
        date: "Sat Mar 31 2012"
    },
]
```

final desired json

```
[
    {
        name: "Bob"
        date: "Thu Mar 29 2012"
    },
    {
        name: "James"
        date: "Fri Mar 30 2012"
    },
    {
        name: "Dylan"
        date: "Fri Mar 30 2012"
    },
    {
        name: "Stanley"
        date: "Sat Mar 31 2012"
    },
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [add](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-add) [all of the models](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-models) from one collection to another:

```
var first = new Backbone.Collection([ { name: "Bob" }, { name: "Joy" } ]),
    second = new Backbone.Collection([ { name: "Ann" }, { name: "Tim" } ]);

second.add(first.models);
console.log(second.models); // logs all four models
```

You could also use several of [Backbone.Collection methods](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection) to filter the models that you want to add:

```
second.add(first.where( { name: "Bob" }));
```

Beware, though, that the Collection's  `url` property usually dictates its Models' URLs. It would not be a good idea to move RESTful Models between Collections with different `url`s.